# Return value from inorder binary tree method

Tags: java, binary-tree, bufferedreader, inorder

I should get the values from the inorder method and then store them in a text file. How can i achieve it in the following code? If i use return to return values to another write method to store in a text file instead of System.out.println, it won't go to the next root.getRight() statement. Any help?

```
private String inorder(TreeNode root) {

        if(root.getLeft()!=null){
            inorder(root.getLeft());
        }

        stringConcatenation += root.getData());

        if(root.getRight()!=null){
            inorder(root.getRight());
        }

        return  stringConcatenation;  
    }   // end of inorder()
```

Comment: This will loop forever if there is more than one element in the tree.  It will traverse to the left most, print it to System, then go right one, and then recursively go left again. It will simply keep printing the first element.

Comment: @CharlieS: No, it won't; when it goes left (or right) in a recursive call, it is going farther down the tree.

Comment: it recurses all the way left to null, then prints what is in the leftmost element. then goes right and reenters. reentry takes it left. it prints the first element again, then goes right. then reenters and goes left. prints the first element, then goes right and reenters. ad infinitum

Comment: "then reenters and goes left": this will now be at a different node than the one that was printed.

Comment: How about using linked List to store data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could concatenate the results from each recursive call with the root value to get a string with the whole list, which could then be returned.

Comment: This might be a feasible way.

Comment: I just posted the change. did you mean this way?@Scott

Comment: You need to do something with what gets returned from your recursive calls.  And you can't add to a variable in its declaration.

Comment: You know how to concatenate to a string; just do it for the recursive calls.  Oh: you'll also need to declare/initialize `stringConcatenation` and return it.

Comment: just posted what you said, is it ok now?

Comment: No; all you did was add the return statement.  It shouldn't even compile (since you never declared `stringConcatenation`).  And you still don't do anything with what each recursive call returns.  If you have `stringConcatenation` as a *global*, that could work, but then you don't need to return anything.